# RealSense camera: stop() cannot be called before start()

Tags: python, flask, realsense

i have a problem on my code.
I need to receive some packages post from antennas and receive the same frame from camera, tryng to tyng up the packgae (json) to the frame.
I have an exception like this:

> stop() cannot be called before start()

and the code looks like:

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime
from app import app
from flask import request,  jsonify
import io, json


i = 0
resp = None
pipeline = None


@app.route("/file-upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload_file():
   
    global pipeline

        #print("Create pipeline")
        #pipeline = create_pipeline()
    pipeline = rs.pipeline()

    cfg = rs.config()
    cfg.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 45)
    pipeline.start(cfg)

    string = request.data
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

    Current_Time = datetime.datetime.now()  # .time() or .date()
    timestampStr = Current_Time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y -- %H-%M-%S.%f")

    if not color_frame:
        print("Color frame non presente")

    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

    if string is not None:
        payload = json.loads(string)
    else:
        resp = jsonify({'message': "Il payload è vuoto"})
        resp.status_code = 404
    try:
        with io.open("./DatasetProva/Json/" + timestampStr+'.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
            # Scriviamo leimmagini sul disco nel path
            str_ = json.dumps(payload,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
            outfile.write(str_)
            #i+=1
            resp = jsonify({'message': "E' stato salvato il json"})
            resp.status_code = 201
        cv2.imwrite("./DatasetProva/Immagini/" + timestampStr + ".jpg", color_image)
        pipeline.stop()
        return resp
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Errore sulla scrittura sul disco ", ex)
        #i-=1

    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True, host ="192.168.1.191",  port="8080")
```

I receive one package from the antenna  every 200/300 milliseconds, is it possible that a new pipeline starts before the old one stops? And how could I solve the problem?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems code in question always runs `stop()` after `start()` so maybe you run different code. You could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables.

Comment: do you have to create new pipeline for every request? Maybe you should create pipeline only once and use it without stop/start ?